# can we say in finite measure that $f_n \to f$ in measure iff every subsequence of $f_n$ coverge almost every where to f

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Assume $(X, \mu )$ be finite measure space

then can we say that

> $f_n \to f$ in measure iff every subsequence of $f_n$ coverge almost every where to f .

My tries :
I know a theorem that states

> $f_n \to f$ in measure iff every subsequence of $f_n$ has a subsequence that coverge almost every where to $f $

Can we give positive answer to the first question from the previous theorem.

Comment: Consider functions that have a little bump on the interval $[k/2^n,(k+1)/2^n]$ and are zero otherwise. Put them in a sequence for all values of $k$ and $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typewriter sequence given by Tao in example 4 [here](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/10/02/245a-notes-4-modes-of-convergence/) is a counter-example to your claim.